# Value not found in Scala program

Tags: scala, intellij-idea

I have just started with Scala so please forgive if this turns out to be silly.

I am trying to implement a linked list in Scala. So, I created a file that contains MyList class and others in `MyList.scala`:

```
abstract class MyList[+A] {
  def head : A
  def tail : MyList[A]
  def isEmpty : Boolean
  def add[B>:A](element: B) : MyList[B] = new MyNonEmptyList[B](element,this)
}

object MyEmptyList extends MyList[Nothing]{
  override def head: Nothing = throw new NoSuchElementException("Head of an Empty list : ")

  override def tail: MyList[Nothing] = throw  new NoSuchElementException("Tail of an Empty list!" )

  override def isEmpty: Boolean = true

  override def toString : String = ""
}

case class MyNonEmptyList[A] (head: A, tail:MyList[A]) extends MyList[A]{
  override def isEmpty: Boolean = false
  override def toString : String = head + ", " + tail.toString
}
```

After carving out the basic functionalities, it was time to test it. So, I created a scala worksheet `test.sc`:

```
object test{
  val list = MyNonEmptyList(1,MyEmptyList)
  val b = list.head
}
```

Now, when I try to run the code (on IntelliJ), I get the following error:

```
Error:(1, 18) not found: value MyNonEmptyList
lazy val list = MyNonEmptyList(1,MyEmptyList)
                ^
```

I do not get the reason behind this error. When I do ctrl+click, I am redirected to the source in MyList.scala file.

Comment: can you share the location of .scala file and test.sc

Answer (score 1):

I don't see any issue with the code you have. Trying the code on scala REPL:

```
scala> :paste
// Entering paste mode (ctrl-D to finish)

abstract class MyList[+A] {
  def head : A
  def tail : MyList[A]
  def isEmpty : Boolean
  def add[B>:A](element: B) : MyList[B] = new MyNonEmptyList[B](element,this)
}

object MyEmptyList extends MyList[Nothing]{
  override def head: Nothing = throw new NoSuchElementException("Head of an Empty list : ")

  override def tail: MyList[Nothing] = throw  new NoSuchElementException("Tail of an Empty list!" )

  override def isEmpty: Boolean = true

  override def toString : String = ""
}

case class MyNonEmptyList[A] (head: A, tail:MyList[A]) extends MyList[A]{
  override def isEmpty: Boolean = false
  override def toString : String = head + ", " + tail.toString
}

// Exiting paste mode, now interpreting.

defined class MyList
defined object MyEmptyList
defined class MyNonEmptyList

scala> val x = MyNonEmptyList(1, MyEmptyList)
x: MyNonEmptyList[Int] = 1,

scala> x.head
res0: Int = 1
```

So the only reason for this error that I can think of is probably your `test.sc` doesn't import `MyList.scala` properly. Could you double check your `#import`?

Comment: I need to use scala worksheet so that I can keep the code on git. I have tried importing, but that doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

The correct way is to:

1. create the test file in a test directory
2. and also to import your file correctly to the test you are performing and not do it with the worksheet.

The worksheet purpose is to do REPL actions and not to test your src files.

Comment: Doesn't work.
I do not think that changing the order of classes has any effect.

Answer (score 0):

Your class may be inside the default package. You should create a new package and move the class to new package.
and import the class to use it

```
import com.testpackage.{MyEmptyList, MyNonEmptyList}

val list = MyNonEmptyList(1, MyEmptyList)

val b = list.head
```

You cannot import the class in Default package.

Hope this helps!

Comment: I hope this helped. I tested as well and worked fine.

Comment: I got an error saying :
`Error:object MyEmptyList is not a member of package com.testpackage
import com.testpackage.{MyEmptyList, MyNonEmptyList}`

Comment: did you create the com.testpackage and moove the MyEmptyList inside that package ?

Comment: Yes. You can check the directory structure here : https://github.com/amita-shukla/functional-programming/tree/master/FunctionalList